# Concatenate symbols from multiple object files into a table (e.g. vtable) at link-time

Tags: linker, vtable, object-files

It might not be possible, but I would like to do something similar to building a vtable at link-time. That is, first I want to emit various function symbols independently, in separate object files. Then, I would like the linker to build a table where the symbols are added sequentially, and be able to refer to the entries in that table.

I have looked into how maybe I could abuse linker scripts and/or relocation entries to build that table, but I couldn't find any satisfactory solution.

Have you ever seen something like that being done? Any tip on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

> I couldn't find any satisfactory solution.

Assume you have `a.o`, `b.o` and `c.o` defining `a()`, `b()` and `c()` respectively.

Create and compile this source:

```
// table.c
extern void a(), b(), c();
void (*table[])() = { &a, &b, &c, 0 };
```

Now link them together:

```
ld -r -o foo.o a.o b.o c.o table.o
```

Voila: you have a table where symbols are all added sequentially.